# FieldItemList::getValue always returns a string, even for a Boolean field

Tags: entities, 9

Supposed I added a custom Boolean field, whose cardinality is 1, to a content type. I create a node of that content type, enter a value for that field (for example, `TRUE`), and save the node.

When I get the field value with `$value = node->get('field_custom')->getValue();` `$value` contains the following array.

```
0 => array (1)
  value => string (1) "1"
```

Is there an way to get the field value that reflects the field type, Boolean in this case?

```
0 => array (1)
  value => boolean true
```

I manually cast the value, for example with code similar to the following one.

```php
// Boolean
$value = (boolean) $value;

// Integer
$value = intval($value);
```

I also tried `get('x')->value` and using `__get()`.

Drupal knows the field type, which is returned from `$field->getFieldDefinition()->getType()`. I take there is a way to correctly cast the field value.

Comment: Values are not cast on return by Drupal.

Comment: You could cast as `$value = (boolean) $value;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally type casting doesn't matter:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/type-casting-variables-in-php-what-is-the-practical-reason-for-doing-this.

So retrieving an entity field value doesn't need to be type casted:

```
$node->field_bool->value
```

returns a string `'0'`/`'1'` or `NULL` if the field is empty. All three possible values work as expected in PHP. `'1'` results in logical true and the other two values in logical false. This reflects how it is visible in UI where a checkbox can only have two states. Empty is unchecked, checked is saved as `'1'` and when unchecked again it is saved as `'0'`.

However, the Drupal entity system is built on typed data and if you want to write OOP code with type casting, you can:

```
$node->field_bool->first()->get('value')->getCastedValue()
```

returns `FALSE`/`TRUE`.

Caveat: This doesn't work on field level. You need to get a field item to get the boolean typed data and you have to catch an empty field to avoid get() on NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur answer, I totally agree, especially with the "normally". So for my case this is very helpful and works good for primitive like integer, float boolean and string wont cast a datetime

Comment: To *cast* a date object replace getCastedValue() with [DateTimeIso8601::getDateTime()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Type%21DateTimeInterface.php/function/DateTimeInterface%3A%3AgetDateTime/9.2.x).