# How do I get a DateTime from a timestamp field?

Tags: entities

Suppose I have a timestamp base field on an entity type. I can do $entity->timefield->value and get the UNIX timestamp.

But how do I get a DateTime object from this?

I can see there is a Timestamp::getDateTime() method which does exactly what I want. But that's the DataType class.

The field definition, TimestampItem, defines the 'value' property as a 'timestamp', so that is the Timestamp datatype. But I can't figure out how to get from one to the other.

Comment: You can instantiate a Datetime object with a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a DrupalDateTime object with `new DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp`.

Comment: Is there not a more elegant way? How can I leverage Timestamp::getDateTime()? More generally, given a field item, how do you get the typed data item for one of its properties?

Comment: Use the method get(), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/305408/fielditemlistgetvalue-always-returns-a-string-even-for-a-boolean-field